# Will everyone get to live during the times of Moshiach?

Tags: messiah

Will everyone get to live during the times of Moshiach or only those that are considered worthy? If not everyone gets to see it what can one do to make themselves worthy or c"v unworthy (are there certain mitzvos/averios)?

Comment: Do you mean who will survive to reach that epoch, or who in that epoch will physically see _moshiach_?

Comment: @mevaqesh I meant more of if everyone will get to live during that time period.

Comment: Could it be possible that all people living in Messianic times be gilguls (possessing the soul of a person of a prior life) and will experience everlasting life? On the other hand, I seem to recall reading somewhere that the messianic era was not intended to be "everlasting", but rather, only for a fixed time, say forty years. Not sure what happens after that.